# Load View with NavigationCacheMode="Enabled" whitout navigate to it

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I would like to know if it is possible to implement this concept:

I have two views:

1 - First view

2 - Second View with NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"

when initializing my application navigates in view 1, I would like to initialize view 2 as well during this phase, without navigating.

example:

my first view is a simple welcome view, my second view is used to view a document. I would like to have a document loaded in view 2 during the initialization of view 1.
So that the user has the document ready when navigating in view 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. Even if you could initialize view 2, but when you call [Frame.Navigate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_NavigationTransitionInfo_) to naviagte to view 2, all UIElements will be re-rendered again.

For your case, you said you have a document that needs to be displayed. I think what you need to think about is how to reduce the loading time. For example, you could display the document by paging instead of showing it at once.